# Como posso filtrar, tanto por Categoria, quanto por Preço?

Tags: ionic, ionic2, angular

Tenho 2 botões de filtro:

1. Ordenar por preço - Que funciona.
2. Ordenar por Categoria - **Não Funciona.**

Gostaria de funcionar o filtro tanto por preço, quanto por categoria.

Ambos são modais e estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

O Ordenar por preço:

Trecho da View que chama a modal:

```
<!-- ORDENA POR PREÇO -->
                <button class="button button-stable button-block  icon-left ion-android-restaurant" modal-select="" ng-model="someModel" options="selectableNames" option-property="role" modal-title="Ordenar por...">Ordenar
                <div class="option">
                      <h1>{{option.name}}</h1>
                </div>
               </button>
```

No Controller está desta forma:

```
    // ORDENA POR...
    $scope.selectableNames =  [
    {name : "Por preço: Do Menor para o Maior", role : "+cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto"}, 
    { name : "Por preço: Do Maior para o Menor", role : "-cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto"},    
  ];


    $scope.getOpt = function(option){     
        return option.name + ":" + option.role;          
    };  
    // FIM DE ORDENA POR
```

E o Filtro, voltando a tela está assim:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="item in ofertass | orderBy: someModel" ng-init="$last ? fireEvent() : null" href="#/nhaac/ofertas_singles/{{item.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta}}" >
```

Esta parte okay!

Agora vamos ao problema?

Para ordenar por categoria, criei uma modal onde filtro apenas as categorias que estão sendo mostradas ao usuário:

```
<ion-view view-title="Escolha as Categorias" hide-nav-bar="false" >
  <ion-content>

        <div class="button-bar">    
            <button class="button button-stable button-block  icon-left ion-android-funnel" ng-click="userCategoria(categoria_comida_nome)">Aplicar Filtro</button>
        </div>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="item in ofertass | unique:'categoria_comida_nome'" ng-model="checkItems[item.categoria_comida_nome]" ng-change="print()">{{item.categoria_comida_nome}}</ion-checkbox>
    </ion-list>

    <div class="button-bar">    
        <button class="button button-stable button-block  icon-left ion-android-funnel" ng-click="userCategoria()">Aplicar Filtro</button>
    </div>


  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

O controller desta modal é assim:

```
// PEGA OS ITENS SELECIONADOS NA MODAL E COLOCA NUM ARRAY
    $scope.checkItems = { };

    $scope.print = function() {
        console.log($scope.checkItems);

    }   

    $scope.save = function() {
        var array = [];
        for(i in $scope.checkItems) {
            console.log($scope.checkItems[i]);
            if($scope.checkItems[i] == true) {
                array.push(i);
            }
        }
        console.log(array);       
        $state.go("nhaac.promocoes");
    }


    // INICIA FILTRO POR CATEGORIA    
      $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('/templates/filters/side-filter.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
      }).then(function(modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
      });
      $scope.abreModal = function() {
        $scope.modal.show();
      };
     $scope.closeModal = function() {    
          $scope.modal.hide();


      };
      // Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
      $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $scope.modal.remove();
      });
      // Execute action on hide modal
      $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
        // Execute action
      });
      // Execute action on remove modal
      $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
        // Execute action
      });

    // FIM FILTRO POR CATEGORIA
```

Minha chamada a esta modal é assim:

```
 <button class="button button-stable button-block icon-left ion-android-funnel"ng-model="someModel" ng-click="checkItems[item.categoria_comida_nome]" ui-sref="filtroPromo">Filtrar                    
                   </button>
```

Ele imprime as categorias selecionadas no console, mas não estou conseguindo mandar este array de volta e aplicar no filtro, que está desta forma:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="item in ofertass | orderBy: someModel" ng-init="$last ? fireEvent() : null" href="#/nhaac/ofertas_singles/{{item.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta}}" >
```

**A Dúvida:** Como posso filtrar, tanto por Categoria, quanto por Preço? O que estou fazendo de errado?

**APENAS PARA ILUSTRAR 100%, SEGUE TODO O CONTROLLER E EM SEGUIDA TODA A VIEW PRINCIPAL:**

```
    .controller("promocoesCtrl", function($scope,$rootScope,$state,$ionicScrollDelegate,$http,$httpParamSerializer,$stateParams,$timeout,$ionicLoading,$ionicPopup,$ionicPopover,$ionicSlideBoxDelegate,$ionicHistory,ionicMaterialInk,ionicMaterialMotion,$ionicModal, sharedCartService,sharedFilterService){

    //put cart after menu
    var cart = sharedCartService.cart;

    // ORDENA POR...
    $scope.selectableNames =  [
    {name : "Por preço: Do Menor para o Maior", role : "+cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto"}, 
    { name : "Por preço: Do Maior para o Menor", role : "-cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto"},    
  ];


    $scope.getOpt = function(option){     
        return option.name + ":" + option.role;          
    };  
    // FIM DE ORDENA POR

// PEGA OS ITENS SELECIONADOS NA MODAL E COLOCA NUM ARRAY
    $scope.checkItems = { };

    $scope.print = function() {
        console.log($scope.checkItems);

    }

        // APLICANDO FILTRO CATEGORIA
        $scope.userCategoria = function(checkItems) {
            console.log("entra na chamada");
//          $scope.userCategoria = $scope.checkItems(function(element) {
                $scope.checkItems;
                console.log("Imprime array");
                console.log($scope.checkItems);
//          };
//            console.log("Imprime array");
//          console.log($scope.userCategoria);
            $scope.modal.hide();
            $state.go("nhaac.ofertas_restaurante");
        };

    $scope.save = function() {
        var array = [];
        for(i in $scope.checkItems) {
            console.log($scope.checkItems[i]);
            if($scope.checkItems[i] == true) {
                array.push(i);
            }
        }
        console.log(array);       
        $state.go("nhaac.promocoes");
    }


    // INICIA FILTRO POR CATEGORIA    
      $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('/templates/filters/side-filter.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
      }).then(function(modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
      });
      $scope.abreModal = function() {
        $scope.modal.show();
      };
     $scope.closeModal = function() {    
          $scope.modal.hide();


      };
      // Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
      $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $scope.modal.remove();
      });
      // Execute action on hide modal
      $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
        // Execute action
      });
      // Execute action on remove modal
      $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
        // Execute action
      });





    // FIM FILTRO POR CATEGORIA


    $rootScope.page_id = "promocoes" ;
    $scope.scrollTop = function(){
        $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle("top").scrollTop();
    };
    // open external browser 
    $scope.openURL = function($url){
        window.open($url,"_system","location=yes");
    };
    // open AppBrowser
    $scope.openAppBrowser = function($url){
        window.open($url,"_blank","closebuttoncaption=Done");
    };
    // open WebView
    $scope.openWebView = function($url){
        window.open($url,"_self");
    };

    // Set Motion
    $timeout(function(){
        ionicMaterialMotion.slideUp({
            selector: ".slide-up"
        });
    }, 300);

    var targetQuery = ""; //default param
    var raplaceWithQuery = "";
    // TODO: Dinamics Promoções
    targetQuery = "json=promocao"; //default param
    raplaceWithQuery = "json=promocao";


    var fetch_per_scroll = 1;
    // animation loading 
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: '<div class="loader"><svg class="circular"><circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></svg></div>'
    });


    $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false; //readmore status
    var lastPush = 0;
    var data_ofertass = [];

    if(window.localStorage.getItem("data_ofertass") !== "undefined"){
        data_ofertass = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("data_ofertass"));
            if (data_ofertass !== null){
            $scope.ofertass = [];
            for(lastPush = 0; lastPush < 10; lastPush++) {
                if (angular.isObject(data_ofertass[lastPush])){
                    $scope.ofertass.push(data_ofertass[lastPush]);
                };
            }
            $timeout(function() {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            }, 500);
        }
    }
    if(!angular.isObject(data_ofertass)){
        $timeout(function() {
        // retry retrieving data
        $http.get("http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_oferta_api.php?json=promocao".replace(targetQuery,raplaceWithQuery)).then(function(response) {
            data_ofertass = response.data;
            if(typeof(Storage) != "undefined"){
                try {
                    window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass",JSON.stringify(data_ofertass));
                } catch(e) {
                    window.localStorage.clear();
                    window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass",JSON.stringify(data_ofertass));
                    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
                    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
                    $state.reload();
                    $scope.$state = $state;
                }
            }
            $scope.ofertass = [];
            for(lastPush = 0; lastPush < 100; lastPush++) {
                if (angular.isObject(data_ofertass[lastPush])){
                    $scope.ofertass.push(data_ofertass[lastPush]);
                };
            }
        },function(response) {
            // error message
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: "error " + response.status,
                template: response.statusText + "<br/>problem: table ofertas",
            });
        }).finally(function() {
            $scope.$broadcast("scroll.refreshComplete");
            // event done, hidden animation loading
            $timeout(function() {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            }, 1000);
        });

        }, 1000);
    }   



    $scope.doRefresh = function(){
        // retry retrieving data
        window.localStorage.clear();
        $http.get( "http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_oferta_api.php?json=promocao".replace(targetQuery,raplaceWithQuery)).then(function(response) {
            data_ofertass = response.data;
            if(typeof(Storage) != "undefined"){
                try {
                    window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass",JSON.stringify(data_ofertass));
                } catch(e) {
                    window.localStorage.clear();
                    window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass",JSON.stringify(data_ofertass));
                    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
                    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
                    $state.reload();
                    $scope.$state = $state;
                }
            }
            $scope.ofertass = [];
            for(lastPush = 0; lastPush < 100; lastPush++) {
                if (angular.isObject(data_ofertass[lastPush])){
                    $scope.ofertass.push(data_ofertass[lastPush]);
                };
            }
        },function(response) {
            // error message
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: "error " + response.status,
                template: response.statusText + "<br/>problem: table ofertas",
            });
        }).finally(function() {
            $scope.$broadcast("scroll.refreshComplete");
            // event done, hidden animation loading
            $timeout(function() {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            }, 500);
        });



    };


    if (data_ofertass === null){
        data_ofertass = [];
    };



    //add to cart function
     $scope.addToCart=function(id,image,name,price){    
        // CHAMA CART.ADD DE SERVICES 
        cart.add(id,image,name,price,1);    

     };   





    // animation readmore
    var fetchItems = function() {
        for(var z=0;z<fetch_per_scroll;z++){
            if (angular.isObject(data_ofertass[lastPush])){
                $scope.ofertass.push(data_ofertass[lastPush]);
                lastPush++;
            }else{;
                $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = true;
            }
        }
        $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");
    };

    // event readmore
    $scope.onInfinite = function() {
        $timeout(fetchItems, 500);
    };

    // create animation fade slide in right (ionic-material)
    $scope.fireEvent = function(){
        ionicMaterialMotion.fadeSlideInRight();
        ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
    };


    // animation ink (ionic-material)
    ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
    $scope.rating = {};
    $scope.rating.max = 5;
})
```

**A VIEW PRINCIPAL**

```
 <ion-view view-title="Promoções" hide-nav-bar="false" >
        <!-- content -->

        <!-- BOTÃO CARRINHO DE COMPRAS -->
            <ion-nav-buttons side="right"   >           
                    <a  href="#/nhaac/carrinho" class="button button-icon icon ion-android-cart" > {{total}} </a>               
            </ion-nav-buttons>

        <ion-content delegate-handle="top" lazy-scroll  id="page-promocoes" class="has-header page-promocoes">

                <ion-refresher pulling-text="Puxe para atualizar..."  on-refresh="doRefresh()"></ion-refresher>
            <ion-list class="list card">
                <div class="item item-input">
                    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                    <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="Procurar" aria-label="filter restaurantess" />
                </div>
            </ion-list>


            <div class="button-bar">      

                     <!-- FILTRA POR... -->
                 <!--    <button class="button button-stable button-block icon-left ion-android-funnel" ng-click="abreModal()">Filtrar</button> -->

        <!--        <a class="button button-stable button-block icon-left ion-android-funnel" ng-model="someModel" options="checkItems[item.categoria_comida_nome]" ui-sref="filtroPromo">Filtrar</a> -->                 

                    <button class="button button-stable button-block icon-left ion-android-funnel"ng-model="someModel" ng-click="checkItems[item.categoria_comida_nome]" ui-sref="filtroPromo">Filtrar                    
                   </button>              

                   <!--   <button class="button button-stable button-block icon-left ion-android-funnel" >
                         Filtrar           
                     </button> -->      


                    <!-- ORDENA POR PREÇO -->
                    <button class="button button-stable button-block  icon-left ion-android-restaurant" modal-select="" ng-model="someModel" options="selectableNames" option-property="role" modal-title="Ordenar por...">Ordenar
                    <div class="option">
                          <h1>{{option.name}}</h1>
                    </div>
                   </button>              

            </div>




            <div class="list animate-fade-slide-in-right">

                <div class="card" ng-repeat="item in ofertass | orderBy: someModel" ng-init="$last ? fireEvent() : null" href="#/nhaac/ofertas_singles/{{item.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta}}" >       



                    <div class="item item-thumbnail-top item-text-wrap">
                        <img class="imagemCapa" image-lazy-loader="lines" image-lazy-src="{{item.cadastra_oferta_foto}}"/>
                        <div class="promocao"><b>{{item.cadastra_oferta_desconto}}% OFF</b></div>
                        <div class="desconto"><b>Apenas: R$ {{item.cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto}}</b></div>

                        <div class="item"><h2><b>{{item.cadastra_oferta_titulo_promocao}}</b></h2></div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <h3>Categoria: {{item.categoria_comida_nome}}</h3>
                            <h3>
                                Preço Normal: <s><small class="preco">R$ {{item.cadastra_oferta_valor_sem_desconto}}</small></s><br>
                                Preço Promocional <small class="preco">R$ {{item.cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto}} </small>
                          </h3>         
                            <div class="to_trusted" ng-bind-html="item.cadastra_oferta_descricao"></div>
                        </div>    
                </div>

                    <div>
                        <center><p style="position:relative;right:10px;bottom:0px;top:1px">
                                <a  ng-click="addToCart(item.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta,item.cadastra_oferta_foto, item.cadastra_oferta_titulo_promocao,item.cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto)" class="button button-assertive button-clear icon-left ion-android-cart"> Pedir Já </a> 
                        </p></center>
                    </div>


                    <a class="item button button-clear button-dark ink" href="#nhaac/ofertas_singles/{{item.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta}}">MAIS INFORMAÇÕES</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ion-list class="list">
            <ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="onInfinite()" distance="5px" ng-if="hasMoreData"></ion-infinite-scroll>
            </ion-list>

            <ion-list class="list">
                <div class="item" ng-if="results.length == 0" >
                    <p>Nenhum resultado encontrado...</p>
                </div>
            </ion-list>


            <ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="10%">
            <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles">
        </ion-infinite-scroll>



        </ion-content>
        <!-- ./content -->
    </ion-view>
```

Comment: Poderia colocar um conteúdo de `ofertass` como exemplo? Isso ajudaria a criar uma resposta funcional.

Comment: Vou editar e colocar.

Comment: Pronto, coloquei mais detalhes. Obrigado.

Comment: Resumindo, você quer realizar ordenação tanto por preço quanto por categoria, sendo preço a de maior relevância?

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o que eu entendi é que você deseja ordenar por 2 campos, de uma olhada aqui nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037524/orderby-multiple-fields-in-angular), tem até um jsfiddle.

Mas ja adiantando, para você ordenar por multi campos faça:

```
ng-repeat="array | orderBy: ['preco', 'categoria']"
```

Assim, é levado em conta que os objetos do seu array possuem os atributos `preco` e `categoria`.

Exemplo:

```
var array = [
    { nome: 'item 1', preco: 1, categoria: 'X' },
    { nome: 'item 1', preco: 1, categoria: 'Y' },
    { nome: 'item 1', preco: 1, categoria: 'Z' },
    { nome: 'item 1', preco: 2, categoria: 'X' },
    { nome: 'item 1', preco: 3, categoria: 'Y' },
    { nome: 'item 1', preco: 2, categoria: 'X' },
    { nome: 'item 1', preco: 5, categoria: 'Z' },
]
```

A ordenação acontecerá sempre da esquerda para direita, ou seja, será ordenado por preço, depois ordenado por categoria, sendo que sempre mantendo a ordem predecessora.

Comment: Fiz a pergunta de forma errada e como há resposta, e muito boas, não posso editar nem deletar, por isso postei a pergunta mais completa em: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189655/como-filtrar-por-categoria-atrav%C3%A9s-de-checkbox-modal-usando-ionic-angularjs @Giovane

Answer (score 2):

Me corrija caso eu esteja errado, porém me parece que você deseja ordenação e não filtragem.

O exemplo a seguir utiliza dados obtidos da URL mencionada no código para realizar ordenação em dois campos baseada em `OrderBy` diretamente no seu `ng-repeat`:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope){

  // Parâmetros preservados no $scope para que possamos utilizar no ng-repeat
  $scope.orderParms = {
    categoria: 'cadastra_oferta_titulo_promocao',
    valor: 'cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto'
  }

  $scope.flipParm = function(p){

  // OrderBy utiliza o caracter '-' (menos) para indicar ordenação inversa.
  // Essa função remove ou adiciona o caracter à especificação de ordenação.

    var tmp = $scope.orderParms[p];
    tmp = (tmp[0] == "-" ? tmp.substr(1) : "-" + tmp);

    $scope.orderParms[p] = tmp;

  };

  // http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_oferta_api.php?json=promocao
  $scope.conteudo = [
    {
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta": "7",
      "fornecedores.nome": "Salgados Fritos",
      "fornecedores.CPF": "02715938659",
      "fornecedores.identidade": "",
      "fornecedores.bairro": "Centro",
      "fornecedores.celular": "34999688888",
      "fornecedores.cep": "38300134",
      "fornecedores.cidade": "Ituiutaba",
      "fornecedores.cod_fornecedor": "3",
      "fornecedores.complemento": "",
      "fornecedores.data_hora_cadastro": "2016-10-10 13:58:05",
      "fornecedores.email": "teste10@teste.com",
      "fornecedores.estado": "MG",
      "fornecedores.logradourro": "Avenida Quinze",
      "fornecedores.numero": "950",
      "fornecedores.responsavel_contato": "ANDRE",
      "fornecedores.telefone_empresa": "34999688888",
      "fornecedores.telefone_responsavel": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_foto": "http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/vovos/_lib/file/img/app_img/coxinha.jpg",
      "cadastra_oferta_titulo_promocao": "Coxinha Frita - 100 unidades",
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor": "3",
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_categoria": null,
      "cadastra_oferta_descricao": "Deliciosa coxinha frita!!!",
      "cadastra_oferta_igredientes": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_tipo_tamanho": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_valor_sem_desconto": "35.00",
      "cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto": "25.00",
      "cadastra_oferta_desconto": "28.57",
      "cadastra_oferta_validade_oferta": "2016-10-31",
      "cadastra_oferta_qtd_estoque": "20",
      "categoria_comida_cod_categoria_com": "54",
      "categoria_comida_data_cadastro": "2016-10-07 23:22:53",
      "categoria_comida_nome": "Salgados Fritos",
      "fornecedor_credito_cod_fornecedor": "3",
      "fornecedor_credito_cod_fornecedor_codigo": "3",
      "fornecedor_credito_qtd_credito": "10"
    },
    {
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta": "3",
      "fornecedores.nome": "Pizzas",
      "fornecedores.CPF": "02727671660",
      "fornecedores.identidade": "m6925660",
      "fornecedores.bairro": "Setor Sul",
      "fornecedores.celular": "34999688877",
      "fornecedores.cep": "38300026",
      "fornecedores.cidade": "Ituiutaba",
      "fornecedores.cod_fornecedor": "2",
      "fornecedores.complemento": "",
      "fornecedores.data_hora_cadastro": "2016-10-06 12:25:34",
      "fornecedores.email": "teste1@teste.com",
      "fornecedores.estado": "MG",
      "fornecedores.logradourro": "Rua Trinta e Cinco",
      "fornecedores.numero": "1212",
      "fornecedores.responsavel_contato": "AndrÃ© Gouveia Nascimento Vilela de Lima",
      "fornecedores.telefone_empresa": "34999688877",
      "fornecedores.telefone_responsavel": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_foto": "http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/vovos/_lib/file/img/app_img/Pizza Calabresa.jpeg",
      "cadastra_oferta_titulo_promocao": "Pizza Grande de Calabresa + Coca-Cola 2 Litros!!!",
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor": "2",
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_categoria": null,
      "cadastra_oferta_descricao": "Deliciosa Pizza de Calabresa....",
      "cadastra_oferta_igredientes": "<p>Calabresa, Mussarela, Molho de Tomate, Cebola e Azeitona!!!</p>",
      "cadastra_oferta_tipo_tamanho": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_valor_sem_desconto": "35.00",
      "cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto": "30.00",
      "cadastra_oferta_desconto": "14.28",
      "cadastra_oferta_validade_oferta": "2016-10-31",
      "cadastra_oferta_qtd_estoque": "50",
      "categoria_comida_cod_categoria_com": "44",
      "categoria_comida_data_cadastro": "2016-07-07 13:55:38",
      "categoria_comida_nome": "Pizzas",
      "fornecedor_credito_cod_fornecedor": "2",
      "fornecedor_credito_cod_fornecedor_codigo": "2",
      "fornecedor_credito_qtd_credito": "10"
    },
    {
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta": "4",
      "fornecedores.nome": "Pizzas",
      "fornecedores.CPF": "02727671660",
      "fornecedores.identidade": "m6925660",
      "fornecedores.bairro": "Setor Sul",
      "fornecedores.celular": "34999688877",
      "fornecedores.cep": "38300026",
      "fornecedores.cidade": "Ituiutaba",
      "fornecedores.cod_fornecedor": "2",
      "fornecedores.complemento": "",
      "fornecedores.data_hora_cadastro": "2016-10-06 12:25:34",
      "fornecedores.email": "teste1@teste.com",
      "fornecedores.estado": "MG",
      "fornecedores.logradourro": "Rua Trinta e Cinco",
      "fornecedores.numero": "1212",
      "fornecedores.responsavel_contato": "AndrÃ© Gouveia Nascimento Vilela de Lima",
      "fornecedores.telefone_empresa": "34999688877",
      "fornecedores.telefone_responsavel": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_foto": "http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/vovos/_lib/file/img/app_img/F C.jpeg",
      "cadastra_oferta_titulo_promocao": "Pizza Grande de Frango com Catupiry + Coca Cola 2 Litros!!!",
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor": "2",
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_categoria": null,
      "cadastra_oferta_descricao": "Deliciosa Pizza de Frango com Catupiry",
      "cadastra_oferta_igredientes": "<p>Frango, Mussarela, Catupiry e Azeitona!!!</p>",
      "cadastra_oferta_tipo_tamanho": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_valor_sem_desconto": "35.00",
      "cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto": "28.00",
      "cadastra_oferta_desconto": "20.00",
      "cadastra_oferta_validade_oferta": "2016-10-31",
      "cadastra_oferta_qtd_estoque": "70",
      "categoria_comida_cod_categoria_com": "44",
      "categoria_comida_data_cadastro": "2016-07-07 13:55:38",
      "categoria_comida_nome": "Pizzas",
      "fornecedor_credito_cod_fornecedor": "2",
      "fornecedor_credito_cod_fornecedor_codigo": "2",
      "fornecedor_credito_qtd_credito": "10"
    },
    {
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta": "5",
      "fornecedores.nome": "Confeitarias & Quitandas",
      "fornecedores.CPF": "02715938659",
      "fornecedores.identidade": "",
      "fornecedores.bairro": "Centro",
      "fornecedores.celular": "34999688888",
      "fornecedores.cep": "38300134",
      "fornecedores.cidade": "Ituiutaba",
      "fornecedores.cod_fornecedor": "3",
      "fornecedores.complemento": "",
      "fornecedores.data_hora_cadastro": "2016-10-10 13:58:05",
      "fornecedores.email": "teste10@teste.com",
      "fornecedores.estado": "MG",
      "fornecedores.logradourro": "Avenida Quinze",
      "fornecedores.numero": "950",
      "fornecedores.responsavel_contato": "ANDRE",
      "fornecedores.telefone_empresa": "34999688888",
      "fornecedores.telefone_responsavel": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_foto": "http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/vovos/_lib/file/img/app_img/kibe(1).jpg",
      "cadastra_oferta_titulo_promocao": "Quibe Frito - 100 unidades",
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor": "3",
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_categoria": null,
      "cadastra_oferta_descricao": "Quibe frito!!!",
      "cadastra_oferta_igredientes": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_tipo_tamanho": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_valor_sem_desconto": "35.00",
      "cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto": "25.00",
      "cadastra_oferta_desconto": "28.57",
      "cadastra_oferta_validade_oferta": "2016-10-31",
      "cadastra_oferta_qtd_estoque": "20",
      "categoria_comida_cod_categoria_com": "46",
      "categoria_comida_data_cadastro": "2016-07-07 13:57:05",
      "categoria_comida_nome": "Confeitarias & Quitandas",
      "fornecedor_credito_cod_fornecedor": "3",
      "fornecedor_credito_cod_fornecedor_codigo": "3",
      "fornecedor_credito_qtd_credito": "10"
    },
    {
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta": "6",
      "fornecedores.nome": "Salgados Fritos",
      "fornecedores.CPF": "02715938659",
      "fornecedores.identidade": "",
      "fornecedores.bairro": "Centro",
      "fornecedores.celular": "34999688888",
      "fornecedores.cep": "38300134",
      "fornecedores.cidade": "Ituiutaba",
      "fornecedores.cod_fornecedor": "3",
      "fornecedores.complemento": "",
      "fornecedores.data_hora_cadastro": "2016-10-10 13:58:05",
      "fornecedores.email": "teste10@teste.com",
      "fornecedores.estado": "MG",
      "fornecedores.logradourro": "Avenida Quinze",
      "fornecedores.numero": "950",
      "fornecedores.responsavel_contato": "ANDRE",
      "fornecedores.telefone_empresa": "34999688888",
      "fornecedores.telefone_responsavel": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_foto": "http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/vovos/_lib/file/img/app_img/kibe.jpg",
      "cadastra_oferta_titulo_promocao": "Quibre Frito - 100 uni",
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor": "3",
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_categoria": null,
      "cadastra_oferta_descricao": "Delicioso Quibre Frito",
      "cadastra_oferta_igredientes": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_tipo_tamanho": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_valor_sem_desconto": "35.00",
      "cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto": "25.00",
      "cadastra_oferta_desconto": "28.57",
      "cadastra_oferta_validade_oferta": "2016-10-31",
      "cadastra_oferta_qtd_estoque": "20",
      "categoria_comida_cod_categoria_com": "54",
      "categoria_comida_data_cadastro": "2016-10-07 23:22:53",
      "categoria_comida_nome": "Salgados Fritos",
      "fornecedor_credito_cod_fornecedor": "3",
      "fornecedor_credito_cod_fornecedor_codigo": "3",
      "fornecedor_credito_qtd_credito": "10"
    },
    {
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta": "1",
      "fornecedores.nome": "Temakes",
      "fornecedores.CPF": "03472925698",
      "fornecedores.identidade": "",
      "fornecedores.bairro": "Setor Norte",
      "fornecedores.celular": "34999999999",
      "fornecedores.cep": "38300070",
      "fornecedores.cidade": "Ituiutaba",
      "fornecedores.cod_fornecedor": "1",
      "fornecedores.complemento": "",
      "fornecedores.data_hora_cadastro": "2016-10-05 13:25:13",
      "fornecedores.email": "ramos@ramosdainformatica.com.br",
      "fornecedores.estado": "MG",
      "fornecedores.logradourro": "Rua Dezesseis",
      "fornecedores.numero": "1511",
      "fornecedores.responsavel_contato": "Ramos de Souza Janones",
      "fornecedores.telefone_empresa": "03432610020",
      "fornecedores.telefone_responsavel": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_foto": "http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/vovos/_lib/file/img/app_img/rocambole.jpg",
      "cadastra_oferta_titulo_promocao": "Rocambole de PrestÃ­gio Gelado",
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor": "1",
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_categoria": null,
      "cadastra_oferta_descricao": "Delicioso rocambole recheado de PrestÃ­gio gelado com coberto com castanhas de caju.",
      "cadastra_oferta_igredientes": "<ul>\n<li>Chocolate.</li>\n<li>Leite consensado.</li>\n<li>Chocolates em pedaÃ§os;</li>\n<li>Coco-Ralado.</li>\n</ul>",
      "cadastra_oferta_tipo_tamanho": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_valor_sem_desconto": "60.00",
      "cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto": "50.00",
      "cadastra_oferta_desconto": "16.66",
      "cadastra_oferta_validade_oferta": "2016-10-31",
      "cadastra_oferta_qtd_estoque": "20",
      "categoria_comida_cod_categoria_com": "45",
      "categoria_comida_data_cadastro": "2016-07-07 13:56:05",
      "categoria_comida_nome": "Temakes",
      "fornecedor_credito_cod_fornecedor": "1",
      "fornecedor_credito_cod_fornecedor_codigo": "1",
      "fornecedor_credito_qtd_credito": "10"
    },
    {
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta": "2",
      "fornecedores.nome": "Temakes",
      "fornecedores.CPF": "03472925698",
      "fornecedores.identidade": "",
      "fornecedores.bairro": "Setor Norte",
      "fornecedores.celular": "34999999999",
      "fornecedores.cep": "38300070",
      "fornecedores.cidade": "Ituiutaba",
      "fornecedores.cod_fornecedor": "1",
      "fornecedores.complemento": "",
      "fornecedores.data_hora_cadastro": "2016-10-05 13:25:13",
      "fornecedores.email": "ramos@ramosdainformatica.com.br",
      "fornecedores.estado": "MG",
      "fornecedores.logradourro": "Rua Dezesseis",
      "fornecedores.numero": "1511",
      "fornecedores.responsavel_contato": "Ramos de Souza Janones",
      "fornecedores.telefone_empresa": "03432610020",
      "fornecedores.telefone_responsavel": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_foto": "http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/vovos/_lib/file/img/app_img/trufadomorango.jpg",
      "cadastra_oferta_titulo_promocao": "Trufado De Morango",
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor": "1",
      "cadastra_oferta_cod_categoria": null,
      "cadastra_oferta_descricao": "Sobremesa gelada composta por uma camada de trufado, morangos, chantily. Decorado com detalhes em chocolate e morangos.",
      "cadastra_oferta_igredientes": "<p><span>obremesa gelada composta por uma camada de trufado, morangos, chantily. Decorado com detalhes em chocolate e morangos.</span></p>",
      "cadastra_oferta_tipo_tamanho": "",
      "cadastra_oferta_valor_sem_desconto": "70.00",
      "cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto": "40.00",
      "cadastra_oferta_desconto": "42.85",
      "cadastra_oferta_validade_oferta": "2016-12-31",
      "cadastra_oferta_qtd_estoque": "3",
      "categoria_comida_cod_categoria_com": "45",
      "categoria_comida_data_cadastro": "2016-07-07 13:56:05",
      "categoria_comida_nome": "Temakes",
      "fornecedor_credito_cod_fornecedor": "1",
      "fornecedor_credito_cod_fornecedor_codigo": "1",
      "fornecedor_credito_qtd_credito": "10"
    }
  ];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    
    Parâmetros de ordenação: 
    <pre>{{orderParms | json}}</pre>
    
    <button ng-click="flipParm('categoria');">Categoria</button>
    <button ng-click="flipParm('valor');">Valor</button>
    
    
    <div ng-repeat = "i in conteudo | orderBy:[orderParms.valor, orderParms.categoria]">
      {{i.cadastra_oferta_titulo_promocao}} <b style="color:red;">{{i.cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto}}</b> <i style="color:#888;">{{i.cadastra_oferta_descricao}}</i>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```