# Como Filtrar por Categoria através de checkbox Modal usando Ionic / Angularjs?

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, ionic

**EDITADO PARA MELHOR EXPLICAÇÃO**

Tenho 3 tipos de filtros:

**Um de pesquisa:**

```
<div class="bar bar-subheader bar-assertive">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper textbox-search">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input ng-model="q" placeholder="Procurar" aria-label="filter restaurantess" />
        </label>
    </div>
```

Onde o filtro de ng-model é: *filter:q*

**Um por ordenação:**

```
  <!-- ORDENA POR PREÇO -->
                <button class="button button-stable button-block  icon-left ion-android-restaurant" modal-select="" ng-model="someModel" options="selectableNames" option-property="role" modal-title="Ordenar por..." has-search="true">Ordenar
                    <div class="option">
                        <h2>{{option.name}}</h2>
                    </div>
                </button>
```

Onde o filtro é: *orderBy:someModel*

**E Preciso de um filtro por Categoria**, que abre um modal listando todas as categorias, mas mostrando somente as categorias que existem listadas (para o usuário não perder tempo selecionando uma categoria que não exista na listagem), onde a View desta modal é:

```
 <ion-modal view-title="cadastrar" hide-nav-bar="false">
    <ion-header-bar>
        <h1 class="title">Escolha as Categorias</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                Estão sendo listadas apenas as categorias existentes em sua localização.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="button-bar">
            <button class="button button-stable button-block  icon-left ion-android-funnel" ng-click="closeModal()">Aplicar Filtro</button>
        </div>

        <ion-list>
            <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="item in ofertass | unique:'categoria_comida_nome' track by $index" ng-model="filtro[$index]" ng-true-value="{{item}}" ng-false-value="" ng-checked="check">{{item.categoria_comida_nome}}</ion-checkbox>
        </ion-list>

        <div class="button-bar">
            <button class="button button-stable button-block  icon-left ion-android-funnel" ng-click="closeModal()">Aplicar Filtro</button>
        </div>


    </ion-content>
</ion-modal>
```

Como na imagem a seguir, **o resultado da modal do código**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os de ordenação e pesquisa, estão funcionando bem.

Mas ***não estou conseguindo uma forma de filtrar as categorias selecionadas pelo usuário.***

**Para ilustrar melhor**, segue a *View completa da minha listagem principal* a qual quero filtrar as categorias:

```
    <ion-view side="center" view-title="vovócooks">


    <!-- BOTÃO CARRINHO DE COMPRAS -->
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right" class="has-header">
        <a href="#/nhaac/carrinho" class="button button-clear button-icon icon ion-ios-cart"> {{total}} </a>

        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-ios-color-filter-outline" id="menu-popover" ng-click="popover.show($event)"></button>

    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <center>
        <div class="bar bar-subheader bar-assertive">
            <label class="item-input-wrapper textbox-search">
                <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                <input ng-model="q" placeholder="Procurar" aria-label="filter restaurantess" />
            </label>
        </div>
    </center>


    <div class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-assertive tabs-color-light">
        <div class="tabs" style="height:70px;">
            <a class="tab-item active" href="#/nhaac/promocoes">
                <i class="icon ion-home"></i> DELÍCIAS CASEIRAS
            </a>
            <a class="tab-item" href="#/nhaac/restaurantes">
                <i class="icon ion-star"></i> VOVÓS ONLINE
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="tabs-striped tabs-color-assertive" >
        <div class="tabs">
            <a class="tab-item active" ng-click="doRefresh()">
                <i class="icon ion-refresh"></i> Atualizar
            </a>

            <a ng-show="checarPermissoes('logado_usuario')" class="tab-item" href="#/nhaac/perfil">
                <i class="icon ion-person"></i> Meu Perfil
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <ion-content delegate-handle="top" lazy-scroll id="page-promocoes" class="has-header page-promocoes">

        <ion-refresher pulling-text="Puxe para atualizar..." on-refresh="doRefresh()"></ion-refresher>


        <div class="list animate-fade-slide-in-right">

            <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 65px;"></div>

                <div class="card" >
                      <div class="item" style="white-space:normal;font-size:12px">
                          <center>
                          <b>Sua localização atual é: </b> {{endereco_atual}}
                          </center>
                        </div>  

                         <center>
                              <button class="button button-clear button-assertive" style="font-size:12px" ui-sref="nhaac.localiza">
                                  Mudar Localização
                              </button>
                          </center> 

                 </div>      

            <div class="button-bar">


                <!-- FILTRA POR... -->

                <!-- FILTRA POR... -->
                <button class="button button-stable button-block  icon-left ion-android-funnel" ng-click="abreModal()">
                    Filtrar
                </button>


                <!-- ORDENA POR PREÇO -->
                <button class="button button-stable button-block  icon-left ion-android-restaurant" modal-select="" ng-model="someModel" options="selectableNames" option-property="role" modal-title="Ordenar por..." has-search="true">Ordenar
                    <div class="option">
                        <h2>{{option.name}}</h2>
                    </div>
                </button>

            </div>



            <div class="card" ng-repeat="item in ofertass | filter:q | orderBy:someModel | unique: 'cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta'" ng-init="$last ? fireEvent() : null" href="#/nhaac/ofertas_singles/{{item.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta}}">



                <div class="item item-thumbnail-top item-text-wrap">
                    <img class="imagemCapa" image-lazy-loader="lines" ng-src="{{item.cadastra_oferta_foto}}" />
                    <div class="promocao"><b>{{item.cadastra_oferta_desconto}}% Off</b></div>
                    <div class="desconto"><b>{{item.cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto | currency}}</b></div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <center>
                            <h2 style="white-space:normal; color:#D95B43;"><b>{{item.cadastra_oferta_titulo_promocao}}</b></h2>
                        </center>
                    </div>

                    <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 8px;"></div>

                    <h3><b>Vovó Cozinheira: </b>{{item.fornecedores_fantasia}}</h3>

                    <div ng-model="item.avaliacao_media">

                        <div ng-show="item.avaliacao_media">
                            <!--                            <h4>Avaliação Média:  {{item.avaliacao_media}} </h4> -->


                            <h4>Avaliação Média

                                <span class="stars alignleft">
                            <span ng-style="{ 'width': getStars(item.avaliacao_media) }">
                        </span></h4>



                        </div>





                        <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 8px;"></div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <h3>Categoria: {{item.categoria_comida_nome}}</h3>

                            <h3><small><b>Descrição: </b>{{item.cadastra_oferta_descricao}}</small></h3>

                            <h3>
                                Preço Normal: <s style="color:red;"><small class="preco"> {{item.cadastra_oferta_valor_sem_desconto | currency}}</small></s><br> Preço Promocional: <small class="preco"> {{item.cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto | currency}} </small><br> Preço do Frete: <small class="preco"> {{item.fornecedor_configura_frete_custo_padrao | currency}} </small>

                            </h3>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <a class="item button button-clear button-assertive ink" href="#nhaac/ofertas_singles/{{item.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta}}"><b>PEDIR</b></a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <ion-list class="list">
            <ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="onInfinite()" distance="5px" ng-if="hasMoreData"></ion-infinite-scroll>
        </ion-list>

        <ion-list class="list">
            <div class="item" ng-if="results.length == 0">
                <p>Nenhum resultado encontrado...</p>
            </div>
        </ion-list>


    </ion-content>
    <!-- ./content -->
</ion-view>
```

Em meu **Controller**, o que **tento** filtrar pelo ***ng-clik*** o trecho é este:

```
// PEGA OS ITENS SELECIONADOS NA MODAL E COLOCA NUM ARRAY
    $scope.checkItems = {};

    $scope.print = function () {
        console.log($scope.checkItems);

    }

    // APLICANDO FILTRO CATEGORIA
//    $scope.userCategoria = function (checkItems) {
//        console.log("entra na chamada");
        //          $scope.userCategoria = $scope.checkItems(function(element) {
//        $scope.checkItems;

//        console.log("Imprime array");
//        console.log($scope.checkItems);
        //          };
        //            console.log("Imprime array");
        //          console.log($scope.userCategoria);
//        $scope.modal.hide();
//        var role = array
//        $state.go("nhaac.promocoes");
//    };

    $scope.save = function () {
        console.log("Chamou o save");
        var array = [];
        for (i in $scope.checkItems) {
            console.log($scope.checkItems[i]);
            if ($scope.checkItems[i] == true) {
                array.push(i);           

            }
        }
        console.log(array);

        $state.go("nhaac.promocoes");
    }


    // INICIA FILTRO POR CATEGORIA    
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('/templates/filters/side-filter.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function (modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
    });
    $scope.abreModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.show();
    };
    $scope.closeModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.hide();


    };  

    // FIM FILTRO POR CATEGORIA
```

Este está bem bagunçado de tantos testes que fiz...

Mas pode ver que pego os dados, e armazeno localmente separados por virgula:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, **estou sofrendo** com a volta **(desconhecimento)...**

Se coloco ***| groupBy: 'mais_campo'*** dá erro.

**Não estou conseguindo fazer este filtro por categorias, e preciso de ajuda.**

**Ou preciso mudar a lógica?** Não sei se por falta de uma lógica melhor (ou conhecimento). **Agradeceria muito...**

Bem, **para finalizar**, ***disponibilizo todo o meu Controller da View Principal:***

```
    .controller("promocoesCtrl", function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $ionicScrollDelegate, $http, $httpParamSerializer, $stateParams, $timeout, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $ionicPopover, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $ionicHistory, ionicMaterialInk, ionicMaterialMotion, $ionicModal, sharedCartService, sharedFilterService) {

         $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                disableBack: false,
                historyRoot: true
            });

//            $ionicHistory.clearCache();
//            $ionicHistory.clearHistory();


        //put cart after menu
        var cart = sharedCartService.cart;

        $scope.endereco_atual = window.localStorage.getItem("endereco_atual");

        if (window.localStorage.getItem("user_des") === undefined) {
            console.log("Usuário logado, setar como logado");



        } else {

            console.log("Usuário deslogado, setar como deslogado");
            var setar = "user_des";
            window.localStorage.setItem("user_des", setar)
        };


        $scope.getStars = function (avalia) {
            // Get the value
            var val = parseFloat(avalia);
            // Turn value into number/100
            var size = val / 6 * 100;
            return size + '%';
        }

        $scope.cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor = $stateParams.cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor;

        $scope.endereco_atual = window.localStorage.getItem("endereco_atual");


        // ORDENA POR...
        $scope.selectableNames = [

            {
                name: "Por preço: Do Menor para o Maior",
                role: "+cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto"
        },

            {
                name: "Por preço: Do Maior para o Menor",
                role: "-cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto"
        },

            {
                name: "Por Maior Desconto (%)",
                role: "-cadastra_oferta_desconto"
        },

            {
                name: "Menor Prazo de Entrega",
                role: "+fornecedor_configura_frete_prazo_entrega_min"
        },

            {
                name: "Maior Prazo de Entrega",
                role: "-fornecedor_configura_frete_prazo_entrega_min"
        },

            {
                name: "Oferta em Ordem Alfabética",
                role: "+cadastra_oferta_titulo_promocao"
        },

            {
                name: "Por Categoria",
                role: "+categoria_comida_nome"
        },



//        {
//            name: "Por Menor valor de Frete",
//            role: "+fornecedor_configura_frete_custo_padrao"
//        },

    ];


        $scope.getOpt = function (option) {
            return option.name + ":" + option.role;
            console.log(option);
            window.localstorage.setItem("OrdenaPor", option.role);
        };
        // FIM DE ORDENA POR

        $scope.filtro = [];

        //função utilizada no filter do ng-repeat
        $scope.devListFilter = function () {
            return $scope.devList.filter(function (item) {
                return $scope.filtro.indexOf(item.categoria_comida_nome) !== -1;
            });
        };
        $scope.pushNotificationChange = function () {
            console.log('Push Notification Change', $scope.pushNotification.checked);
        };

        $scope.pushNotification = {
            checked: true
        };
        $scope.emailNotification = 'Subscribed';

        $scope.save = function () {
            console.log("clicado");
            $state.go("nhaac.promocoes");
        };




        // PEGA OS ITENS SELECIONADOS NA MODAL E COLOCA NUM ARRAY
        $scope.checkItems = {};

        $scope.print = function () {
            console.log($scope.checkItems);
        }

        // APLICANDO FILTRO CATEGORIA
        //    $scope.userCategoria = function (checkItems) {
        //        console.log("entra na chamada");
        //          $scope.userCategoria = $scope.checkItems(function(element) {
        //        $scope.checkItems;

        //        console.log("Imprime array");
        //        console.log($scope.checkItems);
        //          };
        //            console.log("Imprime array");
        //          console.log($scope.userCategoria);
        //        $scope.modal.hide();
        //        var role = array
        //        $state.go("nhaac.promocoes");
        //    };

        //    $scope.save = function (item) {
        //        console.log("Chamou o save");
        //        var array = [];
        //        for (i in $scope.checkItems) {
        //            console.log($scope.checkItems[i]);
        //            if ($scope.checkItems[i] == true) {
        //                array.push(i);

        //            }
        //        }
        //        console.log(array);
        //        window.localStorage.setItem("q", array);
        //
        //        $scope.q = window.localStorage.getItem("q");
        //
        //        $scope.modal.hide();
        //    }


        // INICIA FILTRO POR CATEGORIA    
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('/templates/filters/side-filter.html', {
            scope: $scope,
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function (modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
        });
        $scope.abreModal = function () {
            $scope.modal.show();
        };
        $scope.closeModal = function () {
            $scope.modal.hide();


        };

        // FIM FILTRO POR CATEGORIA



        $rootScope.page_id = "promocoes";

        $scope.endereco_atual = window.localStorage.getItem("endereco_atual");


        $scope.scrollTop = function () {
            $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle("top").scrollTop();
        };
        // open external browser 
        $scope.openURL = function ($url) {
            window.open($url, "_system", "location=yes");
        };
        // open AppBrowser
        $scope.openAppBrowser = function ($url) {
            window.open($url, "_blank", "closebuttoncaption=Done");
        };
        // open WebView
        $scope.openWebView = function ($url) {
            window.open($url, "_self");
        };

        // Set Motion
        $timeout(function () {
            ionicMaterialMotion.slideUp({
                selector: ".slide-up"
            });
        }, 300);


        var targetQuery = ""; //default param
        var raplaceWithQuery = "";
        // TODO: Dinamics Promoções

        $scope.endereco_atual = window.localStorage.getItem("endereco_atual");

        targetQuery = "json=promocao"; //default param
        raplaceWithQuery = "json=promocao";


        var fetch_per_scroll = 1;
        // animation loading 
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<div class="loader"><svg class="circular"><circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></svg></div>'
        });


        $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false; //readmore status
        var lastPush = 0;
        var data_ofertass = [];

        if (window.localStorage.getItem("data_ofertass") !== "undefined") {
            data_ofertass = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("data_ofertass"));
            if (data_ofertass !== null) {
                $scope.ofertass = [];
                for (lastPush = 0; lastPush < 10; lastPush++) {
                    if (angular.isObject(data_ofertass[lastPush])) {
                        $scope.ofertass.push(data_ofertass[lastPush]);
                    };
                }

                $timeout(function () {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                }, 500);


            }
        }
        if (!angular.isObject(data_ofertass)) {
            $timeout(function () {
                // retry retrieving data
                $http.get("http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_oferta_api.php?json=promocao".replace(targetQuery, raplaceWithQuery)).then(function (response) {
                    data_ofertass = response.data;
                    if (typeof (Storage) != "undefined") {
                        try {
                            window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass", JSON.stringify(data_ofertass));
                        } catch (e) {
                            window.localStorage.clear();
                            window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass", JSON.stringify(data_ofertass));
                            //         $ionicHistory.removeBackView();
                            //            $ionicHistory.clearCache();
                            //            $ionicHistory.clearHistory();

                            $state.reload();
                            $scope.$state = $state;
                        }
                    }
                    $scope.ofertass = [];
                    for (lastPush = 0; lastPush < 100; lastPush++) {
                        if (angular.isObject(data_ofertass[lastPush])) {
                            $scope.ofertass.push(data_ofertass[lastPush]);
                        };
                    }
                }, function (response) {
                    // error message
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: "error " + response.status,
                        template: response.statusText + "<br/>problem: table ofertas",
                    });
                }).finally(function () {
                    $scope.$broadcast("scroll.refreshComplete");
                    // event done, hidden animation loading
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                    }, 1000);
                });

            }, 1000);
        }




        $scope.doRefresh = function () {
            // retry retrieving data
            //  window.localStorage.clear();
            $http.get("http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_oferta_api.php?json=promocao".replace(targetQuery, raplaceWithQuery)).then(function (response) {
                data_ofertass = response.data;
                if (typeof (Storage) != "undefined") {
                    try {
                        window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass", JSON.stringify(data_ofertass));
                    } catch (e) {
                        window.localStorage.clear();
                        window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass", JSON.stringify(data_ofertass));
                        //   $ionicHistory.removeBackView();
                        $ionicHistory.clearCache();
                        //    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
                        $state.reload();
                        $scope.$state = $state;


                    }
                }
                $scope.ofertass = [];
                for (lastPush = 0; lastPush < 100; lastPush++) {
                    if (angular.isObject(data_ofertass[lastPush])) {
                        $scope.ofertass.push(data_ofertass[lastPush]);
                    };
                }
            }, function (response) {
                // error message
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: "error " + response.status,
                    template: response.statusText + "<br/>Problema: com a tabela de ofertas",
                });
            }).finally(function () {
                $scope.$broadcast("scroll.refreshComplete");
                // event done, hidden animation loading
                $timeout(function () {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                }, 500);
            });



        };


        if (data_ofertass === null) {
            data_ofertass = [];
        };

        //Coloca produto em destaque
        $scope.addToStar = function (id, image, name, price, supply_id, deliver) {

            console.log(id);
            console.log(name);
            console.log(price);
            console.log(supply_id);




        };


        //add to cart function
        $scope.addToCart = function (id, image, name, price, supply_id, deliver, entrega) {
            // CHAMA CART.ADD DE SERVICES 
            window.localStorage.setItem("fonecedor_carrinho", supply_id);
            window.localStorage.setItem("tipos_pagamentos", tipopag);
            window.localStorage.setItem("frete", deliver);
            window.localStorage.setItem("faz_entrega", entrega);
            cart.add(id, image, name, price, 1, supply_id, deliver);
            $state.go('nhaac.carrinho');

        };

        // animation readmore
        var fetchItems = function () {
            for (var z = 0; z < fetch_per_scroll; z++) {
                if (angular.isObject(data_ofertass[lastPush])) {
                    $scope.ofertass.push(data_ofertass[lastPush]);
                    lastPush++;
                } else {;
                    $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = true;
                }
            }
            $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");
        };



        var tipo = '';

        // $scope.checarPermissoes();

        $scope.checarPermissoes = function (tipo) {
            var permitido;

            if (tipo === 'logado_usuario' && window.localStorage.getItem("user_log") !== null) {
                permitido = true;            
            } else {
                permitido = false;
            }

            return permitido;
        };




        // event readmore
        $scope.onInfinite = function () {
            $timeout(fetchItems, 500);
        };

        // create animation fade slide in right (ionic-material)
        $scope.fireEvent = function () {
            ionicMaterialMotion.fadeSlideInRight();
            ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
        };


        // animation ink (ionic-material)
        ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
        $scope.rating = {};
        $scope.rating.max = 5;
    })
```

Comment: Para oferecer gratificação você precisa alcançar os 75 pontos de reputação, daí aparecerá uma opção aqui embaixo para você vvvvvv

Comment: Obrigado @Math que esta solução minha não é o que quero.

Comment: Só para ilustrar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHvtF.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz uma solução **BEM TABAJARA.**

A aproveitei o ***| filter:q*** do resultado.

Mudei minha modal de Checkbox (Não é o ideal, nem o que queria. O ideal era selecionar mais de uma categoria) para um Radio:

```
 <ion-modal-view  view-title="cadastrar" hide-nav-bar="false">
    <ion-header-bar>
        <h1 class="title">Escolha as Categorias</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                Estão sendo listadas apenas as categorias existentes em sua localização.
            </div>
        </div>

       <div id="home-button-bar5" class="button-bar">
            <button id="home-button72" class="button button-assertive  button-block" ng-click="save()">Filtrar</button>

            <button id="home-button73" class="button button-balanced  button-block" ng-click="limpaFiltro()">Limpar</button>

            <button id="home-button74" class="button button-dark  button-block" ng-click="limpaFiltro()">Cancelar</button>

        </div>

        <ion-list>
            <ion-radio ng-repeat="item in ofertass | unique:'categoria_comida_nome'" ng-model="checkItems[item.categoria_comida_nome]" ng-change="print()" ng-value="item.categoria_comida_nome">{{item.categoria_comida_nome}}</ion-radio>

        </ion-list>


        <div id="home-button-bar5" class="button-bar">
            <button id="home-button72" class="button button-assertive  button-block" ng-click="save()">Filtrar</button>

            <button id="home-button73" class="button button-balanced  button-block" ng-click="limpaFiltro()">Limpar</button>

            <button id="home-button74" class="button button-dark  button-block" ng-click="limpaFiltro()">Cancelar</button>

        </div>

 <!--       <div class="button-bar">
            <button class="button button-stable button-block  icon-left ion-android-funnel" ng-click="save()">Aplicar Filtro</button>
        </div> -->



    </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

E no Controller diz essas chamadas:

```
// APLICANDO FILTRO CATEGORIA
        $scope.userCategoria = function (checkItems) {
            console.log("entra na chamada");

            $scope.modal.hide();


        };

        $scope.save = function (checkItems) {
            console.log("Chamou o save");
            var array = [];
            for (i in $scope.checkItems) {
                console.log($scope.checkItems[i]);              
                if ($scope.checkItems[i] == true) {
                    array.push(i);

                }
            }
            console.log(array);

            window.localStorage.setItem("q",$scope.checkItems[i]);

            $scope.q = window.localStorage.getItem("q");

            $scope.modal.hide();
        }

        $scope.limpaFiltro = function(){

            var limpa = '';

            window.localStorage.setItem("q",limpa);

            $scope.q = window.localStorage.getItem("q");

            $scope.modal.hide();

            $scope.doRefresh();

        };
```

Pronto! Tabajara pro MVP. Quem sabe no futuro consigo a solução ideal.

**Mas e ai? Me dá alguma solução para o verdadeiro objetivo?**